# "I propose you'" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I would like to know if the following sentence is grammatically correct

> I propose you that we do this.

Could you offer an explanation if it's not grammatical correct?

Answer (score 2):

> I propose you that we do this

No, this is not correct because *propose* requires a direct object (the thing which is proposed), for instance:

> I proposed a movie

*I propose you* would mean that *you* is the direct object, which is wrong. Instead the person to whom the proposition is made can be added with *to*:

> I proposed a movie to my friends

If it helps, *to propose* has the same grammatical structure as *to give* or *to send*:

> I gave a candy [to my nephew]
>   I sent a letter [to my friend]

Thus the grammatically correct sentence is:

> I propose **to** you that we do this

Comment: Actually it doesn't have the same grammatical structure as *give* or *send* because those verbs can both take indirect objects:  "I gave my nephew a candy" or "I sent my friend a letter", but not "I propose you a movie."  *Give* and *send* can be intransitive, transitive, or ditransitive; *propose* is only intransitive or transitive.